# BIRT report parameter with multiple values passed from JSP page

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, birt

I have integrated BIRT in web application.I am using Eclipse Luna,JDK 1.8, BIRT Report Engine 4.1.1 and **Data source I am using is Excel Data Source(not JDBC and all that)**. From my JSP page I am passing two parameters in the URL using  Javascript AJAX like:`

```
var reporturl ="/Reporting/loadReport?ReportName="+reportName+"&ReportFormat=html&Supplier=Supplier4&Metal=Gold&Metal=Tin";     

    $("#reportData").html("Loading...<br><img src='/Reporting/resources/images/loading.gif' align='middle' >");

    $('#reportData').load(reporturl ,function(response, status, xhr) {

      if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error getting details ! ";
        $("#reportData").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
```

For report parameter "Metal" I have selected Display type : List Box, Data Type : String and have selected Dynamic Values and then have checked "Allow Multiple Values" checkbox. Then in the Property Editor of table, in Filters tab I have given the expressions as follows:

```
row["Supplier Name"] Equal to params["Supplier"].value
row["Metal"] In params["Metal"].value
```

After this switching to JavaEE perspective in my ReportRenderer.java , I have the following code to get multiple values associated with the "Metal" parameter(which are passed from the URL), I have merged those values as a comma(,) seperated list in a single String variable like :

```
    public static String getParameter( HttpServletRequest request,
        String parameterName )
{

    if ( request.getCharacterEncoding( ) == null )
    {
        try
        {
            request.setCharacterEncoding( UTF_8_ENCODE );
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
        {
        }
    }
    String[] values = request.getParameterValues(parameterName);
    String temp="";
    if(values.length>1)
    {
        int i=0;
       for(i=0;i<values.length-1;i++)
       {
         temp=temp+values[i]+",";
       }
       temp=temp+values[i];
    }
    else
    {
        temp = values[0];
    }

    return temp;
}
```

In a HashMap I am getting all parameters and it's respective values successfully and have set that Map like:

```
HashMap<String,Object> tempMap = new HashMap<String,Object>(); 
    tempMap = discoverAndSetParameters( runnable, request ); 
    for(String str : tempMap.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println("Key : "+str);
        System.out.println("Value : "+tempMap.get(str));
    }
    iRunTask.setParameterValues(tempMap);
```

Here runnable is the object of IReportRunnable and request is the object of HttpServletRequest.
Now when I am running the web application, after clicking on the hyperlink named "Reports" I am getting following exception on console and no output on web page.

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ParameterValidationException: The type of parameter "Metal" is expected as "Object[]", not "java.lang.String".
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.validateAbstractScalarParameter(EngineTask.java:857)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.access$0(EngineTask.java:789)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask$ParameterValidationVisitor.visitScalarParameter(EngineTask.java:706)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask$ParameterVisitor.visit(EngineTask.java:1531)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.doValidateParameters(EngineTask.java:692)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:214)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:86)
```

Please help me how to resolve this problem and again I am specifying I am using Excel Data Source not JDBC or Scripted and all that. I have already gone through many blogs where questions are related to JDBC data source and that didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

When a listbox parameter is declared as "Allow multiple values", the BIRT engine is expecting an array of values, but in your case you send a String.
Therefore when you detect a multi-value parameter, instead of building a comma-separated String you should build a java array of values and pass this array to the parameter map. This way it will work.

Take care elements of this array should have the datatype expected by BIRT: if "Metal" parameter is set as "String" type in your report-design then you shoud be able to use "values" array as it is from getParameter function, otherwise it would be necessary to build a fresh array.